# Tukey HSD function

Tags: r

```
> data.table = data.frame (data = c(A = c(24, 18, 27, 28) , B= c(21, 16, 32, 25), C=c(16, 22, 19, 17)), cat = c(rep('A', 4), rep('B', 4), rep('C', 4)))
> ana = aov(lm(data ~ cat))
> TukeyHSD(ana, 'cat')
```

In the last command, I just want to run the TukeyHSD function for 2 factors.
I have tried to convert 'cat' to c('A', 'B') but it results in an error.
How to modify 'cat' argument correctly? Furthermore, what is the type of 'cat' or why it is enclosed in the single quotation marks ?

Comment: `ana = aov(lm(data ~ cat, data = data.table))`

Comment: @dcarlson Please revert your edits. You removed the issue OP was asking about.